# Microsoft client-login in Java?

Tags: java, minecraft

Im trying to figure out how to get the Token from Microsoft using client-login in Java.
BTW. It is for a Minecraft Launcher, so I need to check if the account owns the game(I do not know how)

I looked to the Documentation but I could not implement the code in my program.
Anyone can help me how I could do it in Java application.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Sorry, but this site is not a discussion forum or programming tutorial site.
Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and read [Ask] to learn how to use this site effectively. 
Also read 
[Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/18157)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's how you could do it, this is a minecraft java mod for fabric but it has the implementation to manage Mincraft player accounts by Microsoft I leave you here the link

Link 1: [github.com | shared](https://github.com/The-Fireplace-Minecraft-Mods/In-Game-Account-Switcher/tree/main/shared)

Microsoft account.java: [MicrosoftAccount.java](https://github.com/The-Fireplace-Minecraft-Mods/In-Game-Account-Switcher/blob/main/shared/src/main/java/ru/vidtu/ias/account/MicrosoftAccount.java)

I also leave you a lib in nodejs, that can be useful but you will have to adapt many things to java.

Nodejs lib: [MSMC](https://github.com/Hanro50/MSMC)

I hope you find it useful

Comment: Thank you really much. I think that should help :)